# onclick in the input field type open flmngr window + select the file and add to the input field the url of the file selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am looking for help to customise the code when onclick in the input field type open flmngr window + selecting the file and adding to the input field the URL of the file selected

```js
window.onFlmngrAndImgPenLoaded = function() {
  
  var elBtn = document.getElementById("btn");
  
  // Style button as ready to be pressed
  elBtn.style.opacity = 1;
  elBtn.style.cursor = "pointer";
  var elLoading = document.getElementById("loading");
  elLoading.parentElement.removeChild(elLoading);
  
  // Add a listener for selecting files
  elBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    selectFiles();
  });
}

function selectFiles() {
  let flmngr = window.flmngr.create({
    urlFileManager: 'https://fm.n1ed.com/fileManager',
    urlFiles: 'https://fm.n1ed.com/files'
  });
  flmngr.pickFiles({
    isMultiple: false,
    acceptExtensions: ["png", "jpeg", "jpg", "webp", "gif"],
    onFinish: function(files) {
      showSelectedImage(files);
    }
  });
}

function showSelectedImage(files) {
  let elImages = document.getElementById("images");
  elImages.innerHTML = "";
  
  var file = files[0];
  
  let el = document.createElement("div");
  el.className = "image";
  elImages.appendChild(el);   

  let elImg = document.createElement("img");
  elImg.src = file.url;
  elImg.alt = "Image selected in Flmngr";
  el.appendChild(elImg);

  let elP = document.createElement("p");
  elP.textContent = file.url;
  el.appendChild(elP);
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
}

#images {
  
  .image {
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 0 #DDD;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 25px 25px 0;
    
    img {
      max-height: 350px;
      border: 1px solid #DDD;
    }
    
    p {
      margin: 5px 0 0 0;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #444;
    }
  }
  
}
```

```html
<h1 class="h5 mb-3">Flmngr file manager: select a single image</h1>

<div id="btn" class="btn btn-primary" style="opacity:0.2;cursor:default">Select image...</div>
<div id="loading" style="font-size:12px">Loading file manager...</div>

<h2 class="h5 mt-5">Selected image</h2>
<div id="images">
  No image selected yet.
</div>

<script src="https://cloud.flmngr.com/cdn/FLMNFLMN/flmngr.js"></script>
<script src="https://cloud.flmngr.com/cdn/FLMNFLMN/imgpen.js"></script>
```

[image: I am looking for something like this]

I am looking for something like this clicking on the input field open the flmngr file manager, clicking or selecting the file, populate the URL of the file to the input field

```html
<input type="text" name="field_name" id="field_name" value="https://fm.n1ed.com/files/book.png" onclick="BrowseServer('field_name');">
```

I really appreciate any help.

Thank you
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to click on the input

```js
window.onFlmngrAndImgPenLoaded = function() {
  
  var elBtn = document.getElementById("FlmngrBrowseServer");
  
  // Style button as ready to be pressed
  elBtn.style.opacity = 1;
  elBtn.style.cursor = "pointer";
  var elLoading = document.getElementById("loadingFlmngrBrowseServer");
  elLoading.parentElement.removeChild(elLoading);
  
  // Add a listener for selecting files
  elBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    selectFiles();
  });
}

function selectFiles() {
  let flmngr = window.flmngr.create({
    urlFileManager: 'https://fm.n1ed.com/fileManager',
    urlFiles: 'https://fm.n1ed.com/files'
  });
  flmngr.pickFiles({
    isMultiple: false,
    acceptExtensions: ["png", "jpeg", "jpg", "webp", "gif"],
    onFinish: function(files) {
      showSelectedImage(files);
    }
  });
}

function showSelectedImage(files) {
  
var file = files[0];
var x = file.url; 
  
document.getElementById("FlmngrBrowseServer").value = x;  
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="configuration[MODULE_PAYMENT_BTC_IMAGE]" value="images/payment_bitcoin.png" id="FlmngrBrowseServer">
<div id="loadingFlmngrBrowseServer"></div>
    
<input type="text" name="configuration[MODULE_PAYMENT_BTC_IMAGE]" value="images/payment_bitcoin.png" id="FlmngrBrowseServer1">
<div id="loadingFlmngrBrowseServer1"></div>
    
    
<script src="https://cloud.flmngr.com/cdn/FLMNFLMN/flmngr.js"></script>
<script src="https://cloud.flmngr.com/cdn/FLMNFLMN/imgpen.js"></script>
```

field and select the file then get the URL link and parse to the input field, but I need a solution for 2 or more input fields.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cpaj1oLf/